# Systemd service does not start with docker

Tags: docker, systemd

I currently have a `systemd` service in my VM that manages lifecycle of a docker image.
I want to support docker kill/service restarts so my container still survives, in case there is a docker container crash.
This is relevant as user install/copies files so is critical to preserve these artifacts.

- I can't run `docker rm` as this will delete underlying file system and I need it. (Need to preserve local files and installations for user)
- I don't want to use `oneshot` as during service startup error is not easy to track real status.
- Docker volumes is not supported in this use case as files as there existing libraries installed in container that can be modified by user.

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Docker Container
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
# Start the container only if it doesn't exist
ExecStart= docker run --name app-container your-image'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop app-container

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Problem:**

When container is killed or service restarts, the systemctl service cannot start anymore.
This can be replicated by doing:

- `docker kill`
- `systemctl stop app-container.service && systemctl start app-container.service`

Error:

```
Sep 24 02:09:21 vm docker[27856]: docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/app-container" is already in use by contai>
```

What I tried?

1. Create a new script to manage Docker lifecycle.
2. New systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=app container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop app-container
ExecStart=/var/lib/run_container.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
```

```
sudo systemctl status app-service.service
● app-service.service - app container
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app-service.service; static)
     Active: deactivating (stop) since Sun 2023-09-24 03:06:51 UTC; 8s ago
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the container exists
if docker ps -a --filter name=app-container | grep -q app-container; then
  # Check if the container is running
  if docker ps --filter name=app-container | grep -q app-container; then
    echo "Container app-container is already running."
  else
    echo "Restarting stopped container app-container."
    docker restart app-container
  fi
else
  echo "Starting a new app container."
  docker run \
     docker-image
fi
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: modifying files inside the container is usually an indicator of a design problem. Can you extend images including the modified files and then run them as containers?

Comment: ...or add a `docker run -v` option so that the part of the container system that contains user data is persisted?  This doesn't really seem like a programming problem; the core problem here is that you need to `docker rm` the old container before you `docker run` a new one (and I'd consider deleting the old container a routine step).

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an odd procedure , but you could run the script for `ExecStart` and also making your whole script in a `while` statement so that it doesn't get stopped when the script is done , also you could add `sleep` command at the end for it to wait a few seconds before checking again.

mainly your error is because you are trying to create a new container with the same name for the container while there is another container with that name.

you should either never use `docker run <image>` in your script (run for the first time manually) or use an `if` statement to check if there is an container with that name or not

keep in mind that when we use `docker run` it is for the moment that the container is not available and when we use `docker start` it is for when the container is stopped for whatever reason.

also you can use `docker run --rm ...` but that would **delete** the container whenever it is stopped which is not what you want.

Hope that helps! :)